# Android global/common functions

Tags: android, class, function, inheritance, global

Just started today to learn Android development, and I just can't find any info on how may I define a `Helper` class, or a collection of functions that will load globally and I'll be able to use them in any Activity that I create.

What I'm planning, is to create (at least for now) 2 functions that will be used almost in every activity, and would be a mess having to define the same functions in every activity.

Which would be the proper way to approach the above?

Comment: You need study about Application Class [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) Extend this class and make some static functions in it, will be accessible in all over the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to throw out a quick note that you should not be putting functions in a global application class for this purpose.  Generally what happens is that if you have shared functionality, you abstract that and put the code in:

- Static methods
- Another package
- A library implementing the functionality against which you link your app
- A content provider

You should explicitly *not* implement this functionality in the `Application` class.  There *are* uses for extending the application, but doing so results in code smell and is a common antipattern for beginners.  If you want a bunch of functionality which is shared in your app, a library is the perfect solution (even if it's just code you separate into another package).  This encourages reuse and allows the code to be more cleanly segmented and tested.

It's common in Java to have either a class or pacakge of the form `*.util` for this.

(I'm guessing you come from something like a Rails world where this is the norm, since Ruby is much more metaprogramming oriented than Java, you generally use different tricks.)

Comment: I actually come from PHP, but I very much thank you for your professional opinion and I will take it in count, as I don't like doing things just to be done... I'd rather spend a little more time, to do it properly

Comment: Just to be sure, by `should explicitly not implement this functionality in the Application class.` you reference to @ChristianStewart's answer as well, right?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a static method in Java.

[Java Static Methods](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html)

In a class Helper,

```
public static void DoSomething(){
}
```

Would be accessible from any class.

Example:

```
Helper.MyFunction();
```

Comment: and almost in every function like that you will need to pass the Activity/Context.

Comment: Correct, you would only need it if you used it.

Comment: I said "almost". And it's good to know, because, you can use one function to dynamically create/inflate views in different activities for ex.